# Given an array A: {${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}$}, for how many permutations of A, $|A_1 - 1| + |A_2 - 2| + \cdots + |A_{10} - 10| = 4$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given an array A: {${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}$}, for how many permutations of A, $|A_1 - 1| + |A_2 - 2| + \cdots + |A_{10} - 10| = 4$

I wrote a basic try-all permutations code for this, and the answer is 52. But I didn't understand the mathematical approach presented in my book. This is my first post here, so sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: Well, there aren't very many ways to get $4$ as the sum of non-negative integers.  Just look at each case.  Note, for instance, that it is not possible for exactly one of those terms to be positive.

Comment: Do you know about cycle notation for permutations?  If so, you can talk more easily about the form of such a permutation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there aren't many ways to get a sum of 4.  Specifically, there's only
$$4 = 3+1 = 2+2 = 2+1+1 = 1+1+1+1$$
and of these, both $4$ and $3+1$ are impossible to realize from a permutation. [Can you see why?]

For each of the others, we can determine the form of the permutation (I'll be using disjoint cycle notation)

- $2+2$ gives the form $(i, i+2)$ where $1\leq i\leq 8$, which represents $8$ permutations
- $2+1+1$ gives the form $(i,i+1,i+2)$ or $(i,i+2,i+1)$ where $1\leq i \leq 8$, which represents $8+8=16$ permutations.
- $1+1+1+1$ gives the form $(i-1,i)(j,j+1)$ where $1< i <j<10$, which represents $\binom{8}{2}=28$ permutations.

In total $8+16+28=52$